# Critical points of nonlinear second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I want to find the critical points of the autonomous nonlinear ODE $y'' = \sin(y) - y'y$. I know these are the points where $0 = y'' = \sin(y) -y'y$.

I'm unsure if I need to solve this system outright. Other than $y = 0$ I'm having a hard time visualizing any other critical points. Any help?

Comment: You may look at the equation also as $\frac{d}{dy}(y') = - \frac{d}{dy}(\cos y + \frac{1}{2}y^{2})$.

Comment: @akech the derivative of $\cos(y)$ equals $-\sin(y)y'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we rewrite the equation as a system:
$$
y'=z,\qquad z'= \sin y - yz,
$$
where $z=y'$, then it becomes clear that the equilibrium points are given by
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
z&=&0\\
\sin y - yz&=&0
\end{array}\right.
$$
or
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
y'&=&0\\
\sin y &=&0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Hence, the equilibrium points are $y=\pi k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @chris102212 Using linearization. This is a separate question that requires a detailed separate answer.